# Product of two Dyson series

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution

Is ${\cal T}\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right]{\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right]$ equal to 1?

I do not think so.

I know that \begin{align}
{\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right] 
&=
I - \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{0}^{t} dt' H(t')   + \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^2 \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{T}\left(\int_{0}^{t} dt' H(t')\right)^2
\\& \quad +
\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^3 \mathcal{T}\left(\frac{1}{3!}\left(\int_{0}^{t} dt' H(t')\right)^3\right) \cdots
\\ & =
I - \frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{t}dt' H(t') + \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^2 \int_{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'}dt'' H(t') H(t'')
\\ & \quad
+ \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^3 \int_{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'}dt'' \int_{0}^{t''}dt''' H(t') H(t'') H(t''') +\cdots
\end{align}

It involves many terms and I do not see them cancel out when calculating the product ${\cal T}\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right]{\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right]$.

Comment: Hi @diff, take a look at my answer below. I dunno what's up with all those people voting to close constructive questions. This question is clearly possible to answer without giving away the derivation.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not equal to $I$.

Supposing that $H(t)$ is *hermitian*, the evolution operator is *unitary*:

$$ U = {\cal T}\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right], $$
$$ U^{-1} = U^{\dagger}. $$

When calculating $U^{\dagger}$, you have to take into account that the ordering of terms in the series reverses:

$$ \left( i H(t') H(t'') \right)^{\dagger} = -i H(t'') H(t'). $$

In other words, Hermitian conjugation doesn't commute with time-ordering.

The true inverse of $U$ is given by an operator

$$ U^{-1} = {\cal T^{-1}} \exp \left[ - \frac{i}{\hbar} \int _0 ^t H(t') dt' \right], $$

where ${\cal T^{-1}}$ is reversed time-ordering (orders strings of $H$ just like ${\cal T}$ does, but reverses the result).

Actually, a more general result holds: in case of oriented paths and *holonomies* of these paths, the inverse holonomy is given by the holonomy of the reversed path. The minus sign in the exponential corresponds to the change of the direction given by $dt'$, and the ${\cal T^{-1}}$ arises naturally through path-reversal.

Comment: Ok i see. I have never seen the symbol of reversed time-ordering before.

Comment: @diff it isn't common notation to denote it as ${\cal T^{-1}}$. In fact, I just invented it :P But it doesn't matter how we call the thing, right?